# Autoresizing Layouts in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, autolayout, cclayer

I'm trying to make a menu in Cocos 2D that will automatically relayout if it's size changes.  With UIKit you can set autoresizing options (either programmatically or through Interface Builder), and I like to do something similar.  Does an option like that exist in Cocos2D for laying out CCLayers (or CCNodes)?